# How does disk encryption mounting work with large disk and low RAM?

Tags: disk-encryption

For example with Truecrypt or bitlocker, when my hard disk contains 500 GB encrypted data and 256 MB Free RAM, how is the data decrypted/disk mounted when I turn on my computer?

If the entire disk is encrypted with the same decryption key, does it require the same amount of RAM to process the data? Or is encryption applied on small blocks and decryption applied by just decrypting those blocks?

Answer (score 2):

In block ciphers (e.g. AES), the data is split into small blocks, and each block of data is processed in sequence. This allows a huge amount of data to be encrypted or decrypted without consuming much RAM.

1. Load one block of plaintext into memory.
2. Encrypt it.
3. Save it.
4. Move to the next block and start again.

And to decrypt:

1. Load one block of ciphertext into memory.
2. Decrypt it.
3. Use / save it.
4. Move to the next block and start again.

In this scheme, it is easy to encrypt or decrypt blocks at random. Unfortunately, this is insecure.

Block ciphers run in a particular [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). The simplest mode (the one I just described) is called ECB, or Electronic Code Book. Each block is processed completely independantly, allowing for each block to be decrypted independantly, as we saw above. Unfortunately, this leads to some serious problems with security, where patterns in the plaintext show up in the ciphertext.

The first image is plaintext, the second is encrypted with a block cipher in ECB mode:

[image: Plaintext]
[image: ECB Ciphertext]

Other modes solve this problem by chaining blocks together using certain operations. This causes the patterns to be dispersed:

[image: Non-ECB Ciphertext]

Most modes of operation (e.g. [Cipher-Block Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29)) will require the previous block to remain in memory. However, since a normal block size is only 32 bytes (256 bits) it doesn't require much memory at all to keep it. However, it does mean that *every* block up until the required block has to be processed first. This is obviously not practical for disk encryption, because to read disk sector 100,001, we'd have to read and decrypt all 100,000 previous blocks.

TrueCrypt uses [XTS](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=modes-of-operation), a special mode of operation designed specifically for storage devices. This allows blocks (or short sequences of them) to be decrypted entirely separately, without losing the security that non-ECB modes such as CBC provide. This means that you can easily decrypt files on the disk without having to decrypt everything else, whilst avoiding the security problems that ECB has.

Comment: That's the exact question I received on my networking exam, with the same pictures :O

Comment: @LucasKauffman They're from the Wikipedia article. Surprise, surprise, academics steal things too! :o

Comment: Those bastards, not even a proper source recognition!

Comment: got it. but how windows kernel RUN ? because its different with image or text.. so crypt tool have to decrypt kernel blocks in memory and write plaintext in disk to load windows correctly ? then later with file recovery tools possible to recover those plaintexts writed in disk before even when system is off ?

Comment: For full system disk encryption TC includes a bootloader that decrypts the boot sector and loads the OS. From there, it provides an abstraction layer that transparently encrypts and decrypts all data going to and from the disk.

Comment: DES is 64bit block size, AES is 128bit. I do not know of any actual 256bit block ciphers however there are a few variable block size ciphers that could be used with 256bit blocks in theory.

Comment: @ewanm89 Threefish has a 256-bit block size variant along with 512-bit and 1024-bit ones (it is a wide block cipher since it was designed for hashing in mind, see Skein). But anyway full-disk encryption uses modes of operation which expand the cipher's block size to the size of a disk sector, so it's not really relevant.

Comment: No, I just didn't like the authoritative 256-bit block size is common... As for mode of operations they don't change the block size as much as group multiple blocks to be processed together.

Comment: @ewanm89 yeah well at this point it becomes more of a terminology issue, in a sense it does become the new block size (but I see your point). :)

Comment: @ewanm89 I should've been more clear - I meant most block sizes were *at most* 256-bit, not that 256-bit was the most common. Even in the case of Threefish, the amount of RAM required to implement them in CBC mode is minimal.

Comment: Yes, one only ever needs to hold a fairly smallish block or set of blocks in memory at any one time. We are talking a few hundred at the most a few thousand bits.

Comment: "_This allows blocks (or short sequences of them) to be decrypted entirely separately, without losing the security that non-ECB modes such as CBC provide._" You have now larger blocks, called "data unit" in TC description, and there is no chaining between data units. An attacker with read access to the disk at different times can gain more information about the amount of modified blocks than he could with chaining between blocks. **Not all the security properties that pure CBC provides are achieved in this mode.**